# Self-learning Book recommendation for topics in ring-theory

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, soft-question, self-learning, advice

I failed badly in my Internal examination in ring theory , and at any cost want to improve upon my grades in the final eamination,with a month and a half to go .... I haven't yet covered the below half of the syllabus.....

> *Factorization and Divisibility in integral domains, Unique Factorization 
>   Domains (UFDs), Principal Ideal Domains (PIDs), Euclidean domains and relationships between 
>   them, Primitive Polynomials and Gauss Lemma, Eisenstein’s irreducibility criterion, Factorization 
>   of polynomials in one variable over a field, Unique Factorization in R[X], R a UFD*

knowing my present condition in algebra,Please if anyone can help me which book I must refer as self study to cover the above topic ,so that the concepts are clear to me...

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Most first year undergraduate abstract algebra texts cover these topics. Perhaps try Abstract Algebra by Anderson and Feil.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118135350.html

Is what I would suggest. It's what I used to learn about almost all the items you've listed. It's not too terse with lots of examples.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reference...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you "  artin " abstract algebra. This is very good for a master levels course of abstract algebra.  And all the topics you mentioned above is covered in it with lots of example. But for studying the ring theory , a good idea of group Theory is important. It's giving you a inner confidence while studying .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Concrete Abstract Algebra. Has a good collection of exercises at the end of each chapter. Author: Niels lauritzen